# Different fixed background-image set to different pages

Tags: html, css

I have 4 5 pages on my website and all I need is a different `background-image` `fixed` for each page and responsive(Scrolling shouldn't affect the image position).
 I can't add the style to the `body` tag because it'll set the image to all pages.
What should I do?

Thank you.

***EDIT:***
Forgot to mention; all pages linked to one CSS file!

Comment: U can declare 5 seperate pages

Comment: Edited the post: all pages linked to one CSS file

Comment: For that you will need a little javascript to do some conditional rendering. Are you just using plan HTML and css?

Comment: No, I have JS files as well! Please, how is that done?

Answer (score 2):

Use different class in body tag. based on that Class name  you can set background images using CSS.

Example:

Page1:

```
   <html>
       <head></head>
        <body class="page-one"> welcome to page one</body>
   </html>
```

Page2:

```
 <html>
      <head></head>
      <body class="page-two"> welcome to page two</body>
   </html>
```

Style:

```
   .page-one{
          background-image:URL("images/bg-one.jpg");
     }

   .page-two{
       background-image:URL("images/bg-two.jpg");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

give each image and/or body tag its own class and link that in the css stylesheet so the edit of one doesn't affect all.